# get delivery status of message has been send with telethon _ Telegram telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to get the status of the message has been send via the telethon client library:

```
client = Telegram("my_session_path")
message =  await clientr.get_messages(username)
```

and I get this info :

```
[Message(id=214, to_id=PeerUser(user_id=50912046926), date=datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 12, 7, 15, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), message='Hello Guys! \n\nThis is my link click here\n\n@my_username', out=True, mentioned=False, media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, from_scheduled=False, legacy=False, edit_hide=False, from_id=1342721360543, fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, media=MessageMediaPhoto(photo=Photo(id=5974260480824422939, access_hash=-8909821964081197779, file_reference=b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\xd6_\\\xa8\x8c\xd7l\x03\xc9E\x00\xb0\xe3\x08\x7f/\xd3 \x92\xf5\x1f', date=datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 12, 6, 37, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), sizes=[PhotoStrippedSize(type='i', bytes=b'\x01\x17(\xca\xa3\x1f\xad \xe6\x82s\xe9Z\x12\x14\xb4\x87\xd6\x92\x80\x174RQJ\xe3\x0c\xf1\x8cRQE+\x80\xa0\xf1\xd2\x93\xbd\x14Qp\n(\xa2\x80?'), PhotoSize(type='m', location=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=400086901230800, local_id=26494), w=320, h=180, size=8911), PhotoSize(type='x', location=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=40230086900800, local_id=26495), w=750, h=422, size=46984)], dc_id=4, has_stickers=False, video_sizes=[]), ttl_seconds=None), reply_markup=None, entities=[MessageEntityTextUrl(offset=32, length=10, url='https://google.com/'), MessageEntityMention(offset=44, length=12)], views=None, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None, restriction_reason=[]), total=51]
```

how can I know the user get the message and read the message?

Comment: check this out, https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messageread.MessageRead, You should store message_id (214 here) in somewhere and then listen to `MessageRead` updates to check for your message,

Comment: @AliPadida tnx for reply . it is possible to query in instance mode . not event base mode?

Comment: What do you mean by instance mode and event mode? Are you referring to function decorator and `add_event_handler` modes to define event handlers?